# How to make a string into another in a column

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a data frame df where I have two columns like this.

```
+-----+------------------+
|x    |       y          |
+-----+------------------+
|0.0  |{12,16,17,18,19}  |
|0.0  |{18,16,17,18,19}  |
|0.0  |{15,16,67,18,19}  |
|0.0  |{65,16,17,18,19}  |
|0.0  |{9,16,17,18,19}   |
|1.0  |{12,16,17,28,39}  |
|0.0  |{24,16,17,28,19}  |
|0.0  |{90,16,17,18,29}  |
|1.0  |{30,16,17,18,19}  |
|1.0  |{28,16,17,18,19}  |
+-----+------------------+
```

from this I wanted something like

```
+---+---+
|x  |y  |
+---+---+
|0  |12 |
|0  |18 |
|0  |15 |
|0  |65 |
|0  |9  |
|1  |12 |
|0  |24 |
|0  |90 |
|1  |30 |
|1  |28 |
+---+---+
```

I tried with

```
println(df  .withColumn("y", df("y".replace("{", "").replace("}","").split(",")(0))).show)
```

Both the columns are String type

But it is printing the same in the y column
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Spark's built-in column functions. Here's an example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("0.0", "{12,16,17,18,19}"),
  ("0.0", "{18,16,17,18,19}"),
  ("0.0", "{15,16,67,18,19}"),
  ("0.0", "{65,16,17,18,19}"),
  ("0.0", "{9,16,17,18,19}"), 
  ("1.0", "{12,16,17,28,39}"),
  ("0.0", "{24,16,17,28,19}"),
  ("0.0", "{90,16,17,18,29}"),
  ("1.0", "{30,16,17,18,19}"),
  ("1.0", "{28,16,17,18,19}")
).toDF("x", "y")

def firstItem(column: Column): Column = split(
  regexp_replace(column, "[{}]", ""), 
  ","
).getItem(0)

df.withColumn("y", firstItem(df("y"))).show
```

Resulting in:

```
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|0.0| 12|
|0.0| 18|
|0.0| 15|
|0.0| 65|
|0.0|  9|
|1.0| 12|
|0.0| 24|
|0.0| 90|
|1.0| 30|
|1.0| 28|
+---+---+
```

More info in the [`functions`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) package documentation and in the [`Column`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) class documentation (for the `getItem` method).

If you need more complex transformations and the built-in functions are not enough, you can use User Defined Functions (UDFs). You can find out more about UDFs [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark-2/spark-sql-udfs.html).

Comment: @Daniel de Paula, Is there any difference in terms of performance between creating UDFs and creating normal functions that accepts `Column` type to use along with `.withColumn()` ?

Comment: @vdep As said in the beginning of the text in the link I've shared in my question, we should always try to use built-in functions before defining UDFs, because UDFs are "black boxes" for Spark and therefore very hard to be optimized. [Here is the link](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark-2/spark-sql-udfs.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df.withColumn("y", regexp_extract($"y", "(\\{)([0-9]*)",2)).show()

+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|0.0| 12|
|0.0| 18|
|0.0| 15|
|0.0| 65|
|0.0|  9|
|1.0| 12|
|0.0| 24|
|0.0| 90|
|1.0| 30|
|1.0| 28|
+---+---+
```